# Оптимизация запроса My SQL

Tags: php, mysql, оптимизация

Решил заняться оптимизацией запросов на интернет-магазине, ибо в таблице товаров уже порядка 15000 наименований, и загрузка страницы стала заметно подтупливать, не критично, но и не особо приятно. Вот хочу посоветоваться с вами, кто, что посоветует.

Есть таблицы: 
1 - t1 - коллекции
2 - t3 - товары (привязаны к коллекции по collection_id)
3 - t3 - характеристики товаров (привязаны к товарам по product_id)

Мы в каталоге выводим коллекции, основываясь на сортировке по характеристикам товаров, запрос получается громоздкий:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    `t1`.`title`,
    `t1`.`id`,
    `t1`.`imgs`,
    `t1`.`price`,
    `t1`.`code_col`,
    `t1`.`brand_id`,
    count(*) as cnt
FROM
    `t1`
INNER JOIN
    `t2` ON `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`collection_id`
INNER JOIN 
    `t3` ON `t2`.`id` = `t3`.`product_id`
WHERE 
    `t1`.`section_id` = 1
    + куча параметров из сортировки по разным таблицам
GROUP BY 
    `t2`.`id`
HAVING
    cnt = 1 (кол-во разных параметров сортировки)
ORDER BY  
    `t1`.`price` * (1 - `sale`), `t1`.`id`
LIMIT 
    0, 30 (и т.д. постраничная навигация по 30 штук на странице)
```

Иногда появляется еще один INNER JOIN с размерами товаров (отдельная таблица размеров, соединяется с товарами по product_id)

Можно ли как-нибудь облегчить сию конструкцию?

Comment: Сам запрос вполне нормальный. Вам помогут индексы.

Comment: На самом деле запрос нормальный только синтаксически (да и то - до определённой версии MySQL), а вообще он более чем странный. Да, типичная неполная группировка. Но если учесть, что в выходном наборе идут поля из одной таблицы, а группировка делается по полю другой, результат становится, мягко говоря, непонятным (особенно с учётом того, что поле выражения группировки вообще игнорируется при выводе). Это если не считать одновременного использования группировки и DISTINCT... при том, что после группировки отбираются исключительно записи с count(*)=1...

Comment: С Explain было бы проще конечно что-то советовать. Рекомендую включить strict режим (это заставит переписать весь запрос) и избавиться от сортировки вида t1`.`price` * (1 - `sale`)

Comment: @Akina , а как правильно писать запросы такого плана? с сортировками по разным фильтрам товара, которые в отдельной базе?